# Quantity of active connections in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

How can I monitor the quantity of active connections in SQL Server 2014 using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio?

Comment: This should probably be asked in ServerFault. It isn't related to programming unless you want to do something different, and think that checking the number of active connections is relevant

Comment: If you click the "Activity Monitor" button in SSMS you'll see all current connections and their state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
```

Answer (score 0):

If active connections  means those connections which are *executing* something right now then one solution is

`sys.dm_exec_requests`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx

"Returns information about each request that is executing within SQL Server."

To get count of active connections we can use:

`SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests 
--Where status = 'Running'`

Note: executing requests/statements can have a status.  Please see doc for sys.dm_exec_requests.status column.